# Unit Testing Service Layer in .NET

Tags: c#, unit-testing, design-patterns, moq

I am developing a new MVC 5 Application.  I have an Integration Layer in my project where I have a service reference to an external web service.

I then created a interface that has some methods - I then have a service class which looks something like below:

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
    private readonly ExternalServiceClient _serviceClient;

    public MyService()
    {
        _serviceClient = new ExternalServiceClient ("WSHttpBinding_IMyService");
    }

    public string GetName(Coordinate[] coordinates)
    {
        string name = string.Empty;

        name = _serviceClient.GetInformationsForCoordinates(coordinates);

        return name;
    }
```

Note this is stripped down and in reality will add try catch block with Exception Handling, etc

I have a Integration.Tests project for Unit Testing of the integration layer.  What is the best practice way of testing the GetName method.  Should I add another Service Reference to the endpoint of the service in the Tests project or if we are using Moq can I create a instance of my actual service that the Web Layer for example will call - and how would that be done?

Comment: Btw you service doesn't seem to do much. Perhaps is better to extract an interface from ExternalServiceClient and pass that as a dependency directly.

Answer (score 14):

The best practice for your situation lies in your architecture design.

Your service obviously depends on `ExternalServiceClient`, and you're intantiating it inside of your `MyService` class, which doesn't allow you to switch the dependency easily, causing you headaches when it's time to test it.

The real question should be:

> How may I design my service in order to make it easily testable?

And the answer is [**`Dependency Injection`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).

Because you will be able to mock `MyService` dependency, you will be able to thoroughly test it and be able to certify, by red-green refactoring, that your service works flawlessly.

In my humble opinion, your class should like this:

```
public class MyService : IMyService {
    public MyService(ExternalServiceClient serviceClient) {
        externalServiceClient = serviceclient;
    }

    public string GetName(Coordinate[] coordinates) {
        string name = string.Empty;
        name = externalServiceClient.GetInformationForCoordinates(coordinates);
        return name;
    }

    private readonly ExternalServiceClient externalServiceclient;
}
```

This way, you will be able to replace your dependency at your will, hence the use of a mock.

Using [**`NUnit`**](http://www.nunit.org/) and **`Moq`**, you could test your service as follows:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyServiceTests {
    [TestFixture]
    public class GetCoordinates : MyServiceTests {
        // Given
        string expected = "Name";
        Coordinate[] coordinates = new Coordinate[] { ... }
        externalServiceClientMock.Setup(esc => esc.GetInformationForCoordinates(coordinates)).Returns(expected);

        // When
        string actual = myService.GetName(coordinates);

        // Then
        externalServiceClientMock.Verify(esc => esc.GetInformationCoordinates(coordinates));
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
    }

    [SetUp]
    public void MyServiceSetup() {
        externalServiceClientMock = new Mock<ExternalServiceClient>("WSHttpBinding_IMyService");
        myService = new MyService(externalServiceClientMock.Object);
    }
    
    private Mock<ExternalServiceClient> externalServiceClientMock;
    private MyService myService;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Will - I am looking into using SimpleInjector for DI for the project. However in the MyService class what is the best way to DI this ExternalServiceClient?

Comment: Constructor injection is the preferred way. See my edit.

Comment: Using a DI tool, you might even injection your `ExternalServiceClient` dependency on the `string` primitive type using some `Conditional Binding`. I don't know about `SimpleInjector`. The real concern is not having any reference to your DI kernel, container or whatever the name within your classes. The DI injection tool shall be referred to only and only in your `Composition Root`, that is, your program entry point.

Comment: Constructor injection can be more clear for API users and easier to document than annotation-based injections, and can be simpler to test. Either type of DI is better than hidden dependencies, but for testing purposes, I prefer explicitly passing them in on the ctor.

Comment: Will - the only thing I dont see on your answer is where to specify the ("WSHttpBinding_IMyService") for the ExternalServiceClient

Comment: It doesn't matter, as your actual object shall be used as an empty reservoir in your mock, and you ought to specify the return value for yourself while setting up the `ExternalServiceClient.GetInformationForCoordinates()` method. The mock requires no `EndPoint`, as it impersonate somehow your service. The mock shall do whatever you tell it to do for the needs of your test.

Comment: Not necessarily in the Mock though - when I come to use the Service in my actual Web Layer - on the Service Layer constructor from your DI example above it is not specified that it is ("WSHttpBinding_IMyService") compared to how it is currently now when the constructor is instantiated

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, your service configuration shall be located in your config file `app.config` or `web.config` along with the type of binding. Then, perhaps shall you have a `IConfigurationProvider` bound to your configuration file so that it returns the required settings automatically on runtime through your composition root.

Comment: Will - correct my service config is in app.config file in Integration Layer - so in Unit test project as you have shown I can create a new mock service in MyServiceSetup method and the initializing the real service should be handled through same composition root as the other DIs in the project - from the global.asax file in the MVC project - am I understanding you correctly?

Comment: No. You're right about the `composition root` located in your `global.asax` file. However, that is good only for your Web project. While running your tests, it is `NUnit` that handles the run, not the ASP.NET web server, making your `global.asax` file useless. I personally have never used any dependency injection tool in my tests, and if I would have done it, I would have put the composition root in a `TestFixtureSetup` method, so that your types registration occurs once on the starting of your tests. Perhaps I would even consider to have a base test class used as my composition root.

Comment: Beside, the use of a DI injection tool within your test will make your tests a bit harder to grasp for a new comer. Letting the new keywords in this case might be as good so to illustrate the intention. Furthermore, if you could have used the same composition root from both the web application and the unit tests, you would have to change your type registration anytime you run either. This sounds like a lot of trouble to me. Thus my preference to use the code as sampled in my answer, or with a specific to your tests composition root using a base test class sounds like the best avenue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51837/discussion-between-will-marcouiller-and-kol)

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is good practice (as you have readonly semantic for `ExternalServiceClient`) to have parametrized constructor to be able to inject the dependency on object construction. Then you can inject the mock in your test case.

In your case, if there is interface(s) that implemented in `ExternalServiceClient`

```
private readonly ExternalServiceClient _serviceClient;

public MyService(IExternalServiceClient serviceClient)
{
    _serviceClient = serviceClient;
}
```

Then use it as:

```
var service = new MyService(new ExternalServiceClient ("WSHttpBinding_IMyService"));
```

and in test

```
IExternalServiceClient  mockObject = //construct mock with desired behabiour then pass to ctor
var service = new MyService(mockObject);
```

If there is no implemented interfaces and ability to add it (since it is external), you must do some tricks with virtuallity.

Comment: Hamlet - so the line var service = new MyService(new ExternalServiceClient ("WSHttpBinding_IMyService")); where the WSHttp is instatntiated - that would be the first line in every method then such as  public string GetName(Coordinate[] coordinates)

Comment: @KOL Is this question?

Comment: yeah that was a question - is it correct that I need this new in every method

Comment: The `new` is necessary every time when you need to create the object(`MyService`), or recreate the context.

Comment: Dependency injection tools such as Ninject, SimpleInjection, StructureMap, etc. are used to avoid having to write `new This(new That(new Here(new There())))` everytime.

Comment: @Will, are you using DI container every time when you have need to create an instance of an object?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: No need, as the DI container resolves the dependency automatically with any call to your dependent object. This keeps one from being obliged to call over `new` over and over again. Furthermore, the DI container MUST never be used from within one's code, hence the need for a so called `Composition Root` by **Mark Seemann**.